# Razor Pages Search Form Does Not Retain Old Value On Back Button Press

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am building an in-house search engine. I have dropdown in a form used in the search. This all in one page. There is search form at the top of the page that used search at all times.

```
<form id="form" method="get" class="form-inline" >
                <div id="divId">
                    <select 
                           asp-for="@Model.TableId"
                            class="m-2 form-control tableName"
                            id="tableName"
                            name="tableName"
                            asp-items="@Model.TableSelectList">
                    </select>
                    <input name="name"/>
                  <button type="submit"/>
               </form>
```

Server side...
public IActionResult OnGet()
{

```
 .....
            var queryList = Request.Query;
         _repo.getTableResults(queryList['tableId'].First());
     .....
    return Page();


}
```

This form submits to the get request and works okay. The issue is when the user clicks the back button, the new value on the table dropdown is retained. it does not reselect the old value. Case in point:

I submit form with table name 'table1'. It searches for table1 and yields results. I then submit 'table2', it yields results. Now I press the back button, and it goes back to the page with the results of 'table1'. The selected value should be 'table1' in the dropdown but it's not. It is still 'table2'.
How do I set the dropdown back to it's original value on back button press?

Comment: You mean the `back button` in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the back button in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going the JavaScript route to load the dropdowns on page load. That way if the user clicks the browser back button, the selected dropdowns are loaded successfully. If there is a better way with razor, please do share.

Comment: We have the same issue, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757222/issue-with-form-data-when-navigating-back-via-browser-in-a-asp-net-core-razor-pa Can you post your solution in more detail?