# Issue with form data when navigating back via browser in a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

We run into an issue with form data when navigating back via browser in a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project. This is how you can reproduce it:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project with this CLI command: `dotnet new webapp -n SelectIssueRepro`
2. Replace the content of the file `Index.cshtml` with this code:

```cs
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form>
    <select asp-for="Year" asp-items="Model.Years" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-select">
    </select>
</form>

<p>
    @Model.Message
</p>
```

3. Replace the content of the file `Index.cshtml.cs` with this code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace SelectIssue.Pages;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Message { get; set; } = default!;

    public SelectList Years { get; set; } = default!;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int Year { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.Year;

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var firstYear = 2017;
        var years = Enumerable
            .Range(firstYear, DateTime.Today.Year - firstYear + 1)
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ToString(),
                Text = x.ToString(),
                Selected = x == Year // Set selected year based on the Year property
            })
            .Reverse()
            .ToList();

        Message = $"You selected year {Year}";
        Years = new SelectList(years, "Value", "Text", Year);

        return Page();
    }
}
```

4. Build and run the project
5. Select the year 2023 from the dropdown. Now the page reloads and shows: `You selected year 2023`
6. Select the year 2022 from the dropdown. Now the page reloads and shows: `You selected year 2022`
7. Now navigate back using the browsers history back button. Now the page reloads and shows: `You selected year 2023` (which is expected) **but the dropdown still shows `2022` (which is not expected, we expect it to show `2023`)**. The same happens for every page while navigating back the history. The value in the dropdown always lags one year behind of what it should show. What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `autocomplete="off"` in your form, the issue will be fixed.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <select asp-for="Year" asp-items="Model.Years" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-select">
    </select>
</form>
```

**Test Result**

[image]